# Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #2: Error inflating class <unknown>

Tags: java, android, xml

My XML file is::

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/abcTv"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@drawable/text_nor"
    android:textSize="@dimen/index_tv_txt" />
```

and code for this portion is:

```
 LayoutInflater inflater = getLayoutInflater();
            //LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater)context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            final View viLin = inflater.inflate(R.layout.abcdeitem, null);

            Log.d("Check ---1", indexListSize+"---"+i);
            final TextView tv = (TextView) viLin.findViewById(R.id.abcTv);

            Log.d("Check ---1", indexListSize+"---"+i);

            tv.setText(tmpLetter);
            tv.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
            if(tempVal.trim().equalsIgnoreCase(tmpLetter.trim()))
            {
                Log.d("Check ---2", indexListSize+"---"+i);
                tv.setTextColor(Color.rgb(90, 17, 17));
                tv.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.text_active);
            }
            else
            {
                Log.d("Check ---3", indexListSize+"---"+i);
                tv.setTextColor(Color.rgb(161, 0, 0));
                tv.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.text_nor);
            }


            viLin.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener()
            {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) 
                {
                    mySearch.setText("");
                    Log.d("LOG", "Click 2");
                    addCountriesInQ();  

                    tempVal=tv.getText().toString().trim();

                    int subitemPosition = sections.get(tmpIndexItem[0]);
                    //ListView listView = (ListView) findViewById(android.R.id.list);
                    getListView().setSelection(subitemPosition);
                    updateList();
                }

            });
            Log.d("Check ---4", indexListSize+"---"+i);
            sideIndex.addView(viLin);
            Log.d("Check ---5", indexListSize+"---"+i);
        }

        sideIndexHeight = sideIndex.getHeight();
```

Error log::

```
  07-07 11:20:31.632: D/Check(15185): **********************************
07-07 11:20:31.680: D/Check 1(15185): 1
07-07 11:20:31.681: D/Check 2(15185): 2
07-07 11:20:31.682: D/Check 3(15185): 3
07-07 11:20:31.732: D/Check 33(15185): 33
07-07 11:20:31.733: D/Check 4(15185): 4
07-07 11:20:31.734: D/Check 5(15185): 5
07-07 11:20:31.734: D/Check 6(15185): 6
07-07 11:20:31.734: D/Check ---(15185): 13---1.0
07-07 11:20:31.737: W/ResourceType(15185): Failure getting entry for 0x7f02005d (t=1 e=93) in package 0 (error -75)
07-07 11:20:31.739: D/AndroidRuntime(15185): Shutting down VM
07-07 11:20:31.739: W/dalvikvm(15185): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40fae258)
07-07 11:20:31.759: E/AndroidRuntime(15185): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
07-07 11:20:31.759: E/AndroidRuntime(15185): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.infotech.supertron.bnicontactapp/com.infotech.supertron.bnicontactapp.MemberContactActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #2: Error inflating class <unknown>
07-07 11:20:31.759: E/AndroidRuntime(15185):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2077)
07-07 11:20:31.759: E/AndroidRuntime(15185):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2104)
07-07 11:20:31.759: E/AndroidRuntime(15185):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:134)
07-07 11:20:31.759: E/AndroidRuntime(15185):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1247)
07-07 11:20:31.759: E/AndroidRuntime(15185):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
07-07 11:20:31.759: E/AndroidRuntime(15185):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
07-07 11:20:31.759: E/AndroidRuntime(15185):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4624)
07-07 11:20:31.759: E/AndroidRuntime(15185):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
07-07 11:20:31.759: E/AndroidRuntime(15185):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
07-07 11:20:31.759: E/AndroidRuntime(15185):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:809)
07-07 11:20:31.759: E/AndroidRuntime(15185):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:576)
07-07 11:20:31.759: E/AndroidRuntime(15185):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
07-07 11:20:31.759: E/AndroidRuntime(15185): Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #2: Error inflating class <unknown>
07-07 11:20:31.759: E/AndroidRuntime(15185):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:608)
07-07 11:20:31.759: E/AndroidRuntime(15185):    at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneLayoutInflater.onCreateView(PhoneLayoutInflater.java:57)
07-07 11:20:31.759: E/AndroidRuntime(15185):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.onCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:655)
07-07 11:20:31.759: E/AndroidRuntime(15185):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:680)
07-07 11:20:31.759: E/AndroidRuntime(15185):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:468)
07-07 11:20:31.759: E/AndroidRuntime(15185):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:397)
07-07 11:20:31.759: E/AndroidRuntime(15185):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:353)
07-07 11:20:31.759: E/AndroidRuntime(15185):    at com.infotech.supertron.bnicontactapp.MemberContactActivity.updateList(MemberContactActivity.java:248)
07-07 11:20:31.759: E/AndroidRuntime(15185):    at com.infotech.supertron.bnicontactapp.MemberContactActivity.onCreate(MemberContactActivity.java:139)
07-07 11:20:31.759: E/AndroidRuntime(15185):    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:4479)
07-07 11:20:31.759: E/AndroidRuntime(15185):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1050)
07-07 11:20:31.759: E/AndroidRuntime(15185):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2041)
07-07 11:20:31.759: E/AndroidRuntime(15185):    ... 11 more
07-07 11:20:31.759: E/AndroidRuntime(15185): Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
07-07 11:20:31.759: E/AndroidRuntime(15185):    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.constructNative(Native Method)
07-07 11:20:31.759: E/AndroidRuntime(15185):    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:417)
07-07 11:20:31.759: E/AndroidRuntime(15185):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:588)
07-07 11:20:31.759: E/AndroidRuntime(15185):    ... 22 more
07-07 11:20:31.759: E/AndroidRuntime(15185): Caused by: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: Resource is not a Drawable (color or path): TypedValue{t=0x1/d=0x7f02005d a=-1 r=0x7f02005d}
07-07 11:20:31.759: E/AndroidRuntime(15185):    at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawable(Resources.java:1932)
07-07 11:20:31.759: E/AndroidRuntime(15185):    at android.content.res.TypedArray.getDrawable(TypedArray.java:608)
07-07 11:20:31.759: E/AndroidRuntime(15185):    at android.view.View.<init>(View.java:2791)
07-07 11:20:31.759: E/AndroidRuntime(15185):    at android.widget.TextView.<init>(TextView.java:454)
07-07 11:20:31.759: E/AndroidRuntime(15185):    at android.widget.TextView.<init>(TextView.java:447)
07-07 11:20:31.759: E/AndroidRuntime(15185):    ... 25 more
07-07 11:20:33.466: I/Process(15185): Sending signal. PID: 15185 SIG: 9
```

It gives error at the time layout called.

Comment: What is `text_nor` in @drawable/text_nor?

Comment: Check your resource,as its saying :android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: Resource is not a Drawable (color or path):

Comment: @GiruBhai I have been given the resource XML file, there is only one TextView

Comment: @Raghunandan it's a background color

Comment: @SatyakiMukherjee then you should have `@color/red` for example and then in `colors.xml` have resource red defined there. Is `text_nor` a image?. remove the background and try once

Comment: @Raghunandan thanks for the heads up on my answer.

Comment: @Raghunandan thanks for ur help, bcz I have placed @drawable/text_nor to drawable-hdpi folder, and my phone support by drawable-large-mdpi..... so for this reason this error comes. please post your answer. I will accept this.

Comment: @SatyakiMukherjee sure. But if its a color then its better to define it in colors.xml

Comment: @Raghunandan yes u r absolutely correct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Caused by: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: Resource
>   is not a Drawable (color or path): TypedValue{t=0x1/d=0x7f02005d a=-1
>   r=0x7f02005d}

Andorid cannot find the reource `@drawable/text_nor`. Check if you have the specifed drawable in the respective drawable folders.

As commented by op

I have placed @drawable/text_nor to drawable-hdpi folder, and my phone support by drawable-large-mdpi

From your comments

> it's a background color

Also if text_nor is a color then define the color code in colors.xml and refer the same as `@color/name`

Comment: Your answer gives me a way to solve the error. Thanks Raghunandan with +1